# No compatible version found

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have cloned an existing project. After performing `npm install`, I got this error:

```
npm WARN package.json sdk@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: chokidar-socket-emitter@'>=0.5.1 <0.6.0'
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget ["0.0.1","0.0.2","0.1.0","0.1.1","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.3.0","0.3.1"]
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'sdk'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     c:\GIT\mas\Rapid\hide\npm-debug.log
```

Here's the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "sdk",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install && bower install --production && jspm install && node src/tools/updateDependencies.js && npm run bundle-dep",
    "_jspm": "jspm install",
    "_postjspm": "node src/tools/updateDependencies.js && npm run bundle-dep",
    "bundle-dep": "jspm bundle \"src - [src/**/*] - [components/**/*]\" www/bundle.js",
    "start": "node dev-server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "jspm": "^0.17.0-beta.12",
    "typings": "^0.7.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
    "chokidar-socket-emitter": "^0.5.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "spdy": "^3.2.3"
  },
  "jspm": {
    "name": "sdk",
    "directories": {
      "lib": "src"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "angular2": "npm:angular2@2.0.0-beta.15",
      "es6-shim": "github:es-shims/es6-shim@^0.35.0",
      "json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@^0.1.0",
      "systemjs-hot-reloader": "github:capaj/systemjs-hot-reloader@^0.5.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "os": "github:jspm/nodelibs-os@^0.2.0-alpha",
      "plugin-typescript": "github:frankwallis/plugin-typescript@^4.0.5"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@^0.2.0-alpha",
      "net": "github:jspm/nodelibs-net@^0.2.0-alpha",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@^0.2.0-alpha",
      "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.2",
      "rxjs": "npm:rxjs@^5.0.0-beta.2",
      "tty": "github:jspm/nodelibs-tty@^0.2.0-alpha",
      "util": "github:jspm/nodelibs-util@^0.2.0-alpha",
      "zone.js": "npm:zone.js@^0.6.6"
    },
    "overrides": {
      "npm:angular2@2.0.0-beta.15": {
        "main": false,
        "dependencies": {
          "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.2",
          "rxjs": "npm:rxjs@^5.0.0-beta.2",
          "zone.js": "npm:zone.js@^0.6.6"
        },
        "peerDependencies": {
          "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.2",
          "rxjs": "npm:rxjs@^5.0.0-beta.2",
          "zone.js": "npm:zone.js@^0.6.6"
        },
        "jspmNodeConversion": false,
        "map": {
          "crypto": "@empty"
        },
        "meta": {
          "src/*.js": {
            "deps": [
              "reflect-metadata",
              "zone.js"
            ]
          }
        },
        "format": "detect"
      },
      "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.2": {
        "map": {
          "crypto": "@empty"
        }
      },
      "npm:typescript@1.8.9": {
        "browser": {},
        "map": {
          "buffer": "@empty",
          "child_process": "@empty",
          "fs": "@empty",
          "path": "@empty",
          "process": "@empty",
          "readline": "@empty"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I already updated my `npm` as said [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4984), but still no effect. What should I do?

Comment: @randy which part? there are many "dependencies" objects.

Comment: One more suggestion - remove white spaces from path you are providing. ex - Programs Files. Use "\" for white space or "_" to remove white space between two strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version you are trying to install is not provided by NPM. If you read the error message you see that `3.1` is the latest release they currently serve, you are installing `5.1`.

You can fix this by removing the `chokidar-socket-emitter` in `devdependency` in your `package.json`, and run this command:

`npm install chokidar-socket-emitter --save-dev`

That will install version 3.1.